# How can I export shortcut sets and shortcut links in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, navigation, users, features, importing-exporting

I am using Drupal 7 and I have some **shortcut sets** (per role using the [shortcut per role](https://drupal.org/project/shortcutperrole) module) **and shortcut links** in them and I would like to **export** them either using the **features** functionality or with any other exporting mechanism.

But I do not find any relevant exportables in the features exporting options not even in the **Strongarm** section. Is there a way yo do this or should I manually recreate them in the other site installations?

I have also seen a [relevant question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46173/is-it-possible-to-export-arbitrary-configurations) but it does not have any answers regarding the shortcuts part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, managed to **programmatically** create the shortcut sets and links with the following php script:

```
<?php
echo 'populating shortcuts...';
$shortcut_set = new stdClass();
$shortcut_set->title = 'Default';
$shortcut_set->set_name = 'shortcut-set-1';
$shortcut_set->links = array(
    array('link_path' => 'admin', 'link_title' => 'Admin',),
);
shortcut_set_save($shortcut_set);
echo ' shortcuts population finished';
?>
```

as mentioned in this [drupal post](https://drupal.org/node/1175700).

A also had to apply this [patch](https://drupal.org/files/fix-shortcut-set-save-1175700-10.patch) in shortcut module, which fixes the shortcut_set_save function called by the script.